# Make a servlet thread safe in java

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I have working code as follows

```
public class receive_meter_to_store extends HttpServlet {

    WSEMAMSTS EMAMService = new WSEMAMSTS();
    ItronEMAMStsBinding itronEMAM = EMAMService.getItronEMAMStsBinding();


    ItronAuthCredit lItronAuthCredit = new ItronAuthCredit();


    EANDeviceID lTerminalID = new EANDeviceID();


    EANDeviceID lClientID = new EANDeviceID();


    SimpleDateFormat itronDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    Date current_datetime = new Date();
    String s_current_datetime = itronDF.format(current_datetime);

    MsgID lMsgID = new MsgID();
    reuse_func gc_reuse_func = new reuse_func();
    curr_time gs_current_datetime = new curr_time("");

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String retdata = "Failure";

        try {
            retdata = add_meter_to_store(request, response);
        }
        finally {
            out.println(retdata);
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

I want to make it thread safe, as in to make it run faster. First I am to remove all the global variables, but when i do so, I get error

"An unhandled program error has occured. Please contact the Support services and report the issue"

I have moved them so they can be local as follows

```
public class receive_meter_to_store extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String retdata = "Failure";

        reuse_func lc_reuse_func = new reuse_func();

        try {

            WSECMPublic EMAMService = lc_reuse_func.getMeterWebService();

            ItronEMAMStsBinding itronEMAM = EMAMService.getItronEMAMStsBinding();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            String ErrorMsg = ex.getMessage();

           out.println("Error" + ErrorMsg);
        }
        finally {
            out.close();
        }

        try {
            retdata = add_meter_to_store(request, response);
        }
        finally {
            out.println(retdata);
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

the class i am calling add_meter

```
public String add_meter_to_store(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    { 
        reuse_func lc_reuse_func = new reuse_func();

        try
        {

            WSECMPublic EMAMService = lc_reuse_func.getMeterWebService();

            ItronEMAMStsBinding itronEMAM = EMAMService.getItronEMAMStsBinding();


            ItronAuthCredit lItronAuthCredit = new ItronAuthCredit();

            EANDeviceID lTerminalID = new EANDeviceID();


            EANDeviceID lClientID = new EANDeviceID();


            SimpleDateFormat itronDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            Date current_datetime = new Date();
            String s_current_datetime = itronDF.format(current_datetime);


            MsgID lMsgID = new MsgID();

            curr_time ls_current_datetime = new curr_time("");

            // Declare MeterImportResponse Variable
            ItronMeterStsImportResp stsImportResp = new ItronMeterStsImportResp();

            // Call meterStsImport WebMethod
            stsImportResp = itronEMAM.meterStsImport(stsImportReq);



        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO handle custom exceptions here
            String ErrorMsg = ex.getMessage();
            retdata = "Error : " + ErrorMsg;
        }

        return retdata;
    }
```

Note: i have removed the global variables in first part and put them in the class

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting?

Comment: when i call a method using , stsImportResp = itronEMAM.meterStsImport(stsImportReq);  i get the exception error An unhandled program error has occured. Please contact the Support services and report the issue

Comment: you have to try blocks and finally associated with them. if there is any execption in your first try block catch block fwill fire and after thst finally and your are closing out. Aftr that it will process the second try block then finally block. But in that situation if out is already clode and will result again in exception.

Comment: post your stacktrace if you have.

Comment: *"I want to make it thread safe, as in to make it run faster."* ... thread safety and performance are two unrelated goals.  There are occasions in which a developer will decide to compromise speed (performance; eg. employing mutual exclusion with locks) in order to provide correctness (thread safety).

Comment: scottb, thats what i want to do

Comment: https://goo.gl/MO24T0

Comment: https://goo.gl/upFcm9

Comment: those are two projects, have a look

Comment: compare the classes receive_meter_to_store.java,

Answer (score 2):

The problem (or one problem, at least) is that in the first `finally` block, you close `out`, but then try to use it again later.

This means that your `out.println(retdata)` statement is always operating on a closed stream.

Comment: yes for sure, if i get an exception in the first place, i want it to exit

Comment: @Ruth see update to answer: the problem occurs regardless of whether there is an exception.